# node mysql connection.connect does not work

Tags: mysql, node.js

Having an odd issue with node mysql. I am running a mysql container (docker) on my local machine with a standard setup. I am able to get past mysql.createConnection, but my code always fails at connection.connect. MySQL Error logs on the container show no attempted/failed connections, and I can connect via Workbench. Has anyone had this experience trying to connect to MySQL via node.

```
router.get('/page', function(req,res){
  const msg = 'My Query from config, tested and confirmed on Workbench';

  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'user',
    password : 'pw',
    database : 'db',
    port     : 3306,
    debug    : true
  });

  console.log('Connect to server', connection.state); //Doesn't get past this guy

  connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
      return err;
    }
    else {
      console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
    }
  });

  middleware.logger.debug('Make Query');
  connection.query(msg, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
        res.json('We got some rows!');
      }
    else {
      console.log('Error while performing Query.', err);
      res.json(err);
      }
  });
  console.log('End Connection');
  connection.end();
});
```

Also, should note: I get the same error whether my docker container is running or not.

EDIT: Okay, want to amend my problem, this is actually an issue with express router. Expanded code above.

Comment: Does the err.stack show any errors?

Comment: Since you say you can connect with Workbench, I am assuming that you have exposed the ports correctly on the docker container?

Comment: That statement doesn't print. The last print statement that runs is 'Connect to server'.

Comment: Yes, the ports are exposed on 3306, and I set the bind addresses to allow traffic. .

Comment: Can you turn on any more error reporting or turn off all firewalls as a quick test?

Comment: Your code works fine on my box. Could it be a faulty installment of mysql module? That's a very odd problem and I don't think a firewall has any reason to be at fault. An error would be thrown ( we are on a local machine anyway )

Comment: Hmmm, that's interesting... Maybe I need to just delete my node_modules and run a fresh npm install. I am on a work machine with encryption and firewalls, but that hasn't been a problem in the past. 

Anyways, I'm going to try and remove the mysql npm and reinstall it.

Comment: I don't know the full setup of your project, but local firewalls such as Windows Firewall can be helpful to disable many times and it takes 30 seconds to rule out.

Comment: Okay, so I reinstalled NPM, and completely isolated the batch of code from the master code. I got a full response from MySQL, but am getting this error: error connecting: Error: Cannot enqueue Handshake after already enqueuing a Handshake.

Comment: I am having almost exact issue. Have you had any progress? My issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50098176/node-cant-connect-to-vagrant-box