# Node Can't connect to vagrant box

Tags: node.js, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am not sure if this is the correct place to ask my question, but really I am out of ideas, and my clock is ticking.
In short, I got a new machine that I need to make development ready.
This project is based on rather old program versions, that is a task to update. 
In short I have set up the Vagrant (1.8.1) in VirtualBox (5.0.14). Chef (0.10.0) created all dependencies successfully and I can SSH to machine and see all is fine, all services are running as set in VagrantFile.

Vagrant box is latest ubunty/trystu64. My host machine is MacOs HighSierra(10.13.3).

Now, I open for example an mySQL editor (mySQL Workbench) and it connects to the Box, I can see DB and manipulate it.

My problem is with the NodeJS (I think). When I run my tests, it simply refuses to connect to the Box. More precisely, it attempts to connect to 127.0.0.1: 3306 (mySQL) and it errors. While MySQL Workbench performs the same connection without problems.

It seems the port forwarding in Vegrant works fine, as mySQL workbench is being forwarded to a box. Nodejs is not being forwarded, or something.
Is it Node doing it? Something else that I need to allow?

I have tried many different things, I have lost count. And always the same issue.
Is there something that I can do to Node, so it behaves as mySQL Workbench? Any idea is appreciated.

This identical setup used to work before, but not now.

Comment: Does the node run in the vagrant or in the machine?, in case the node runs inside the vagrant, mind that `127.0.0.1` will not be the true loopback. That also explains why you can connect from the workbench (assuming the workbench is in the machine)

Comment: It is a huge application. It runs on the machine. Only purpose of the Vagrant is to provide Database services (MySQL and Redis). There are probably many other services, but I need only Redis and MySQL. And both are failing with the same symptoms...

Comment: I mean, that if you have a vagrant, unless you did some forwarding in your machine, a mysql server running inside the vagrant will not be available in the `127.0.0.1` from your machine. 
The same for the redis inside the vagrant. If you want to use those services, grab the vagrant ip address and use that for node to connect to the services. But correct me if I'm wrong, for which addresses is your vagrant creating network interfaces?

Comment: Machine is freshly installed. That is strange. As soon as the Vagrant is up, I can connect to it via Workbench. Node can't, as there is something that prevents it. But IMO it cant be firewall, as the Workbench would not work then.

Comment: Check node.js connection, check db credentials in node.js are ok, and check the versions of node-mysql and the mysql server for possible known problems.. Have a look at the comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43502313/5476782), the user has the same issue you have. As a note, have a look at the error that node.js receives and add it to your question. It might help a lot :)